# Helping with curl and C# - basic (GoPay project)

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl

Can anyone help me with curl and .NET? I have red main parts of curl documentation and some topics on this server but still don't know (how to format data paramaters, headers etc.).
For instance, I need to send this curl request:
(gopay project)

```
curl -v https://testgw.gopay.cz/api/oauth2/token \
-X "POST" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-u "<Client ID>:<Client Secret>" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=payment-create"
```

And later something like this (bigger data):

```
curl -v https://testgw.gopay.cz/api/payments/payment \
-X "POST" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer xzZnu3YnAHRk298EwdettFQMcbCcvmwTKKfhrJx2aGG8ZnFyBJhAvFW547WVSD7p" \
-d '{
      "payer": {
                  "default_payment_instrument":"BANK_ACCOUNT",
                  "default_swift":"FIAFZPP",
                  "contact":{"first_name":"Petr1",
                             "last_name":"Pan"
                            }
                },
      "amount":"100",
      "items":[{"name":"item01","amount":"500"},
               {"name":"item02","amount":"500"}
              ],
      "callback":{
                  "return_url":"http://www.eshop.cz/return",
                  "notification_url":"http://www.eshop.cz/notify"
                }
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, working exaple (first part):

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://testgw.gopay.cz/api/oauth2/token");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";            
        string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", "testid", "testecret");
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials);
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        string authorization = String.Concat("basic ", base64);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string data = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=payment-create";

            streamWriter.Write(data);
        }

        WebResponse wr = request.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var json = "[" + content + "]"; // change this to array
        var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  
        foreach (JObject o in objects.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
            {
                string name = p.Name;
                string value = p.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```